# Read XML data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to read xml data in the xml file.
I have a table column consist with the xml data. [image]

if i click on the xml file it will open in the Sql server Management studio.
xml file format shown below.

[image]

I want to read only NTDomainName, DatabaseName and ServerName and write that data in the another Table. Table format shown below

```
NTDomainName | DatabaseName | ServerName 
----------
ABC          | TestCube1    | SERXYZ
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<event><data name="NTUserName"><value>MyName</value></data><data name="NTDomainName"><value>DomainName</value></data><data name="ServerName"><value>ServerName</value></data></event>'

select [NTDomainName], [DatabaseName], [ServerName] from
(
    select [name],[value] from (
        select c.value('./@name', 'varchar(100)') [name], c.value('(./value)[1]', 'varchar(100)') [value]
        from @xml.nodes('/event/data') as t(c)
    ) a where [name] in ('NTDomainName', 'DatabaseName', 'ServerName')
) x
pivot (
    max(value) for [name] in ([NTDomainName], [DatabaseName], [ServerName])
) as [pivot_Name]
```

The most inner query will retrieve information from XML, one row for every `name` attribute value, that you want to retrieve. So, output of this query needs to be pivoted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
event_data_XML column has 4 rows containing with xml files. 
How to read one by one and  display in the one select statement.

Comment: @GayanHemachandra If my answer satisfied your erquirements, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. event_data_XML column has 4 rows containing with xml files. How to read one by one and display in the one select statement.

Comment: @GayanHemachandra That wasn't your original question. You asked how to pull data from XML. Try finishing on your own, not asking for entire solution. This isn't free code providing service.

Answer (score 1):

i think you look for this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
CAST(f.x.query('data(@name)') as varchar(150)) as data_name,
CAST(f.x.query('data(value)') as varchar(150)) as data_value
FROM @xml.nodes('/event') as t(n)
CROSS APPLY t.n.nodes('data') as f(x)) X
PIVOT (MAX(data_value) FOR data_name IN (NTDomainName, DatabaseName, ServerName)) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[XML] XML
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([XML])
VALUES ('<event><data name="SessionID">S1</data><data name="NTUserName">User1</data><data name="DatabaseName">DB1</data><data name="ServerName">SN1</data></event>')
      ,('<event><data name="SessionID">S1</data><data name="NTUserName">User2</data><data name="DatabaseName">DB2</data><data name="ServerName">SN2</data></event>');

SELECT [ID]
      ,MAX(CASE wHEN C.value('(./@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  = 'NTUserName' THEN C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  END) AS [NTUserName]
      ,MAX(CASE wHEN C.value('(./@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  = 'DatabaseName' THEN C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  END) AS [DatabaseName]
      ,MAX(CASE wHEN C.value('(./@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  = 'ServerName' THEN C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  END) AS [ServerName]
FROM @DataSource
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('event/data[@name = "NTUserName" or @name = "DatabaseName" or @name = "ServerName"]') T(c)
GROUP BY [ID];
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. event_data_XML column has 4 rows containing with xml files. How to read one by one and insert into the @DataSource table

Comment: @GayanHemachandra Not sure, I am understanding the issue. Could you provided sample data and desire output?